# How to know if PostgreSQL COPY is alive

Tags: postgresql

I am import a table (5GB) into a remote server (PostgreSQL 9.6) using pgAdmin 4, and the import process has been running for 2 days.

I want to know if the import process is alive or dead. get the import process is best. I am using wireshark to capture import TCP package,and get nothing useful imformation.

How to solve the situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several methods:

- See if the backend process on the database server consumes CPU.
- Look into `pg_locks` if the backend is blocked.
- Check the `pg_stat_activity` row for the backend and see its state.

How big is the file and how many rows does it contain?

Comment: 1.5GB of the file,and 45000000 rows contain.

Comment: Yes, two days is pretty long for that. Are any triggers defined on the table? Lots of indexes?

Comment: I find the reason is that the net is too slow,i copy the 1.5GB to server side and import success in 15min.I am in China Chongqing,and the server in Ameria.